# Append message to JBoss Console using jboss-log4j.xml

Tags: jboss, console, log4j

I'm unable to append messages from my application to the JBoss console. The following are the changes that I made to the jboss-log4j.xml configuration file:

```
<category name="com.tricubes">        
  <priority value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</category>
```

Here is my code:

```
public class OneToOneValidation2 {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.tricubes");

public boolean validate(byte[] fpImage, byte[] fpTemplate, String desc, String ticket) {
    ...
        logger.info("BES INFO: SOCKET MSG SENT " + intToByteArray(x));            

    ...
    return b;
}
```

}

What am I missing?

TIA!

Edited:

The console appender. Also is the default appender used by JBoss.

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
  <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
  <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>

  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
  </layout>
```

I have tried with both org.jboss.logging.Logger and org.apache.log4j.Logger;

Answer (score 0):

`Category` is deprecated (use `Logger`), and `Priority` is not recommended (use `Level`). So your config block should be:

```
<logger name="com.tricubes">        
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</logger>
```

Also, what is your `CONSOLE` appender defined as? If its not pointing at the JBoss console, it wont log there.

Comment: The jboss-log4j.xml is included with the default JBoss 5.1 GA distribution. It is still using the category and priority tags. JBoss is using the configuration file for its own console & file loggings. I have tried your recommendation but it is still not logging my messages to the console. I have edited the question to include the console appender I'm referring to in my logger / category section.

Comment: Are you getting any errors when trying to instantiate OnlyOnceErrorHandler? If so, you need to add jboss commons dependency.

Comment: Nope, I didn't get any errors at all.. it was just silently ignoring my configurations.